# How do I tell how many threads a Linux binary is creating without source?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Suppose I have a generic binary without source and I want to determine whether it is running serially or spawns multiple threads.

Is there a way I can do this from the linux command line?

Comment: You can use `top` or `htop` to find it or even use gdb and arbitrarily halt the program and check the threads it has spawned.

Comment: Monitor the program with `strace` and look for the `fork` or `clone` system calls.

Comment: How can I figure out where to set an instruction-level breakpoint if the program only takes seconds to run?

Comment: Also %50 of Linux binaries can be decompiled so as to extract most of the source code. I believe Netbeans has an import from binary command.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: `fork()` is not involved in thread creation.

Comment: @alk but fork might use the clone syscall, in which case ltrace could be used to weed out the instances of close due to fork.

Answer (score 4):

First install `strace`.

```
$ yum install strace
```

Run the program with strace, and look for `clone` or `fork` system calls.  Here's a quick example with a program I wrote that just calls `fork` and returns.

```
$ strace ./a.out 

execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x74f000
...
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fb22b16da10) = 6567
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Yes, that how I'd do it. To print the number of threads on stdout:

 `strace ./a.out 2>&1 | grep -c clone`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ps` for that. From `man ps`:

```
-L     Show threads, possibly with LWP and NLWP columns.
```

So you can do:

```
$ ps -L <pid>
```

and it will show you something like this:

```
 PID   LWP TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
4112  4112 ?        Sl    65:35 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
4112  4116 ?        Sl     0:04 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Each line of the output corresponds to one thread. This of course, only works for a certain 
moment in time. To track the spawning of threads, use strace, as suggested by Jonathon Reinhart.

An alternative to `strace` is, of course, `gdb`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643884/gdb-multithreading) for details on managing threads in gdb. You may also read the [thread section](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) of the gdb manual. Quick introduction:

```
$ gdb /usr/lib/firefox/firefox <pid>
[... initialization output ...]
> info threads    # lists threads
> thread <nr>     # switch to thread <nr>
```

Your comment:

> How can I figure out where to set an instruction-level breakpoint if the program only takes seconds to run?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440643/gdb-breakpoint-on-pthread-create) might help you here, as it shows how to break on thread creation (with `pthread_create`) using gdb. So every time a thread is created, execution stops and you might investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Just run: `cat /proc/<pid>/stat | awk '{print $20}'` to get the number of threads of a running process.

[proc manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)